# Moving Cross-country with 2 Cats

Tags: cats, house-moving

I'll be moving across the US with a U-Haul truck and a car in-tow and need to accommodate for 2 cats that travel in rabbit cage size containers.  Leaving the cats in the towed car is illegal in many states and there is not enough space for them in the truck cab.  What are other options for making this move with the cats?

Comment: Could you please add some more detail?

Answer (score 3):

Thank you for your question!   Moving is very stressful for cats. You want them with you, while you're driving, so you can comfort them.  They also need to be in an area where the temperature is regulated.  It can get hot inside a carrier.

**SMALL, SOFT CARRIERS:**  You can put your kitties in smaller carriers so they will fit in the cab with you. They will sleep most of the time. So, they don't need much room.  If there will be people in the cab with you, they can hold a carrier on their lap. This way they can reach in and comfort the kitties.  Expect a lot of howling at first because they will be scared.

For example, you can get a small soft carrier that will be easy to fit anywhere. Here's a picture of mine:
[image: soft carrier]

**MAKE STOPS EVERY FEW HOURS:**  You will also need to make stops every few hours to let them out to use the litter pan and drink water and eat.  Be careful to keep all doors closed so they do not run outside.  This also gives them a chance to get out of the carrier and walk around the cab.  Don't expect them to use the litter pan the first time you let them out.  They will probably be too scared.  Bring their favorite treats with you and try to get them to eat a few. You don't want them to eat too much because some cats get motion sick.  Let them roam around the cab for about 15 minutes each stop.

**THE BEST OPTION:**. Another, more expensive option is to have two family members or friends stay behind and fly to your destination with the cats. This is actually the best choice. It will be less stressful for the cats because it's a much shorter trip.  This is the option I chose when moving from Florida to Texas.  Make sure to read the airline regulations for pets in economy.  When I travelled years ago, it was one pet per person and two pets in economy per flight.  Back them, it was $50 per pet.  They have to be in a carrier that will fit under the seat in front of you.  Don't travel with them in cargo.  This will be to stressful for them.

I hope this gives you some alternatives!  Best wishes to you and your kitties...and safe travels!